# By what magic ?! : multiswap in 1 block + paradoxal transactions?

Tags: swaps

By what magic this is possible ?
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x3f95c3fbddda52c8c07a1b1a0e8ced33a6b71a17cbbd82bf688cd45e23c5f4fd

1. How to make multiple swap in one block (look section call "Transaction Action" not "Tokens Transferred")
2. How can you have : swap1 : Token_A -> Token_B, swap2 : Token_B -> Token_C, when user dont have token_B yet ?

Thank you for your answers :)

Comment: `How to make multiple swap` - implement it in a contract function and then call that function.

Comment: `How can you have : swap1 : Token_A -> Token_B, swap2 : Token_B -> Token_C, when user dont have token_B yet` - swap2 takes place only after the user **does have** token B.

Comment: @goodvibration how Token_B -> Token_C deal is not time dead by the time swap1 take place ? (it took less than 30 sec for the all thing to execute) are you sure this was 1act by 1act. it looks like it was multi-thread for that short time

Comment: There's no such thing as "multi-thread" on the blockchain!

Comment: A block is added to the chain every 13-15 seconds or so. A transaction that you submit can take an arbitrary duration, and how fast it is depends on your gas-price as well as other factors such as the current state of the network.

Comment: @goodvibration true, I guess what I ment is "async"

Comment: Again - there is no such term "async" on the blockchain. No concurrency. You're probably referring to offchain tools.

Comment: understood. thank you! Do you have examples of contracts that handle multi-swap ? I could not find any, thanks again

Comment: Like I said, you just implement a contract function which executes these swaps sequentially, one by one. There's nothing too special about this, just a pretty standard contract function.

Comment: @airu The transaction you linked uses 1inch exchange that has sources verified on Etherscan https://etherscan.io/address/0x11111254369792b2ca5d084ab5eea397ca8fa48b#code.